# How to deal with uneven number of samples in classification?

Tags: classification, sample

Suppose we have **2 labels: 0** and **1**.

The data number with **label 0** is **1000** but the data with **label 1** is just **100**.

In this situation, the **training of classification** will be **bias** to the result of label 0.

What can be done in this scenario?

Can we **generate** samples **manually** corresponding to label 1?

If we can do so, how to **validate** that the generated samples possess the same **properties/characteristics** as the original data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this aricle](http://rikunert.com/SMOTE_explained).
It's about a method called **SMOTE** which stands for *Synthetic Minority Over-sampling Technique*. 
Basically if you have data distributed like this (small number of red dots, larger number of green dots):
[image]

You synthesize new samples around the existing ones:
[image]

This method is one of the commonly used ones and it is described in greater detail in the article linked above. There are other simpler methods like removing some datapoints from the majority class or duplicating some of the ones in the minority class.

The images have been taken from the article.

Comment: you need to answer what OP is asking in question (a good approach) e.g Can we generate samples manually corresponding to label 1?